# MemoryError when merge two data frame with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two huge dataframe : 
First dataframe : limdata

```
        SACC_ID     OPPLINE_LINE_ID     OPP_CREATION_DATE
    0   001A000000qqefQIAQ  a0W1200000F5TWOEA3  2015-01-09
    1   001A000000siuo7IAA  a0W1200000JEmTdEAL  2017-01-02
    2   001A000000qqCDcIAM  a0W1200000H3FYTEA3  2016-01-15
    3   001A0000014MJgpIAG  a0W1200000F5TW9EAN  2015-01-09
    4   001A000000ZdyuMIAR  a0W1200000H11lHEAR  2015-12-10
    5   001A000000aOmo4IAC  a0W1200000H11n3EAB  2015-12-10
    6   001A000000v6diCIAQ  a0W1200000HkwfzEAB  2016-05-02
    .....
    151185  001A000000skyIMIAY  a0WA000000EMTouMAH  2014-09-12
```

and the second dataframe called hist

```
SACC_PS     CASE_ID     CREATION_DATE
    0   0011200001K64ncAAB  5001200000eXVMvAAO  2017-01-25 05:00:07
    1   001A000000iUrwSIAS  5001200000eX7FMAA0  2017-01-25 05:06:38
    2   001A0000011lNmnIAE  5001200000Xyi38AAB  2016-03-04 13:02:19
    3   001A000000aOlebIAC  5001200000XyE0TAAV  2016-03-04 13:02:09
    5   001A0000013XIPoIAO  5001200000XyG0LAAV  2016-03-04 13:02:12
    7   001A000000aOkIoIAK  5001200000XyLT3AAN  2016-03-04 13:02:12
    9   001A000000m5pCAIAY  5001200000XyKhsAAF  2016-03-04 13:02:12
    11  001A000000yLcL4IAK  5001200000Xyg2wAAB  2016-03-04 13:02:12
    ....
    12473746    001A000000aOkumIAC  5001200000gXsWHAA0  2017-05-02 16:20:59
```

I try to merge these two dataframe using this line of code :

```
case = pd.merge(limdata, hist, left_on='SACC_ID',right_on='SACC_PS')
```

But I got this error related to memory :

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 case = pd.merge(limdata, hist, left_on='SACC_ID',right_on='SACC_PS')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py
>   in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index,
>   right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
>        56                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
>        57                          validate=validate)
>   ---> 58     return op.get_result()
>        59 
>        60
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py
>   in get_result(self)
>       594             [(ldata, lindexers), (rdata, rindexers)],
>       595             axes=[llabels.append(rlabels), join_index],
>   --> 596             concat_axis=0, copy=self.copy)
>       597 
>       598         typ = self.left._constructor
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
>   in concatenate_block_managers(mgrs_indexers, axes, concat_axis, copy) 
>   5201         else:    5202             b = make_block(
>   -> 5203                 concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),    5204                 placement=placement) 
>   5205         blocks.append(b)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
>   in concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy)    5336
>   concat_values = to_concat[0]    5337         if copy and
>   concat_values.base is not None:
>   -> 5338             concat_values = concat_values.copy()    5339     else:    5340         concat_values =
>   _concat._concat_compat(to_concat, axis=concat_axis)
>
> MemoryError:

Can you help me please to resolve this problem? 
Thank you in advance

Bests

Comment: You can filter before merge .

Comment: @W-B How? can you give me a help please? thanks

Comment: Have you tried with dask?

Comment: @user32185 no.. what is dask?

Comment: @W-B In Nasri's examples there are no filters.
Nasri the idea is that if you have to apply some filters is better to do so before the merge.

Comment: yes but i do not nedd filter.; I need all of these lines

Comment: @Nasri [dask](https://dask.org/) allows you to do out-of-memory computations. The API is basically the same as pandas.